# Any way to do a headless update of a modern macOS?

Tags: macos, software-update

Is there anyway to update macOS where it never prompts you for anything? That is, you, somehow, start the update, and when you come back the update is complete.

I'll put in the caveat for a machine that's not using an encrypted drive, although that would be wonderful as well.

Currently, updates are multi-phase events that require interaction. You can't just kick off the update overnight and have the machine up and ready in the morning.

Comment: Are you including the download phase in this question?

Comment: Use softwareupdate(1) from a shell prompt.